# chain of responsiblity design pattern gives error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

This codes give me eror:"ConcreteHandler1 : Handler" and others.Error: "not all code paths return a value " error in functions?

```
  public abstract class Handler
    {
         protected Handler BirSonrakiAdim;
        public void NextStep(Handler BirSonrakiAdim)
        {
            this.BirSonrakiAdim = BirSonrakiAdim;
        }
        public abstract ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat);
    }


public class ConcreteHandler1 : Handler
    {
        public override ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat)
        {

            if (mevduat > 0 && mevduat < 1000)
            {
                return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;
            }
            else if (BirSonrakiAdim != null)
            {
                BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
            }
            else
                return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;

        }
    }


   public class ConcreteHandler2 : Handler
    {
        public override ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat)
        {

            if (mevduat > 1000 && mevduat < 3000)
            {
              return ReturnFaiz.faiztype2;
            }
            else if (BirSonrakiAdim != null)
            {
                BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
            }
            else
                return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;
          }
    }


 public class ConcreteHandler3 : Handler
    {
        public override ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat)
        {
            if(mevduat>3000)
            {
                return ReturnFaiz.faiztype3;
            }
            else if(BirSonrakiAdim!=null)
            {
                BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
            }
            else
                return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;
         }
    }



public enum ReturnFaiz
    {
        faiztype1=20,
        faiztype2=30,
        faiztype3=40
    }



   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ;
            }
        }

        protected void BtnHesapla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Handler h1 = new ConcreteHandler1();
            Handler h2 = new ConcreteHandler2();
            Handler h3 = new ConcreteHandler3();

            h1.NextStep(h2);
            h2.NextStep(h3);

            Label1.Text= h1.HandleRequest(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way , It's not the pattern that give you the error, Patterns can't give errors.

Answer (score 4):

In your elseif statement in public override ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat) you are not returning anything...
so should be:

```
    if (mevduat > 0 && mevduat  1000 && mevduat 3000)
    {
        return ReturnFaiz.faiztype3;
    }
    else if(BirSonrakiAdim!=null)
    {
        return BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
    }
    else
        return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;
```

Comment: Interesting. If you're getting the error "not all code paths return a value" then I don't see what else it could be. There does seem to be one more issue in the code though. In the If statement mevduat 1000 and 3000 has no operator (== or < or > or anything) but I thought that might be the pasting.

Comment: i add new version my question. Please help me!

Comment: You are missing the return keyword from each time you call BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
The HandleRequest has a return type, which means that you ALWAYS have to return something. so it should be return BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);

Answer (score -1):

You say your methods returns a `ReturnFaiz` enum, but in the `else if` clauses you return nothing, because after it passes through the `else if` the code that does return something is never visited. Which is not valid because your method claims you do return something, and that's a promise the compiler intends you to keep.

What you could do is declare a `ReturnFaiz` that is called Empty (I would advice to make up more readable names for faiztype1 etc) and has a value of -1. Then you return that at the bottom of every method as a sort of default return value: if the method hasn't returned when it reaches that, it will return `ReturnFaiz.Empty`.

So:

```
public enum ReturnFaiz
{
    Empty = -1,
    faiztype1=20,
    faiztype2=30,
    faiztype3=40
}

public class ConcreteHandler2 : Handler
{
    public override ReturnFaiz HandleRequest(int mevduat)
    {

        if (mevduat > 1000 && mevduat < 3000)
        {
          return ReturnFaiz.faiztype2;
        }
        else if (BirSonrakiAdim != null)
        {
            BirSonrakiAdim.HandleRequest(mevduat);
        }
        else
            return ReturnFaiz.faiztype1;

        return ReturnFaiz.Empty; // default return value if nothing else applies.
    }
}
```